# Can't get params from get request - Node JS, Angular

Tags: node.js, angular

I have this angular method that gets features. I only need the features that have the releaseid that I pass with paramters.

```
getFeatures() {
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.featureService.getFeatures(params['releaseid']).subscribe(res => {
      this.features = res;
    })
  });
}
```

My service (featureService):

```
getFeatures(releaseId) {
  const uri = 'http://localhost:4000/features';
  return this
          .http
          .get(uri, {params: {releaseId: releaseId}})
          .map(res => {
            return res;
          });
}
```

My nodejs route

```
featureRoutes.route('/features').get(function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.params);
});
```

But the req.body.params is undefined.

Any help on this?

Comment: GET requests don't have a body (PUT or POST do however). what do you expect to be in the body of the request?

Comment: You won't get params on ```request.body``` for get request, it will be ```request.params```.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**Service (featureService):**

```
getFeatures(releaseId) {
    const uri = 'http://localhost:4000/features?releaseId=' + releaseId;
    return this.http.get(uri);
}
```

**Nodejs route:**

```
 featureRoutes.route('/features').get(function (req, res) {
     console.log(req.params); // should contain your releaseId
 });
```

You should now be able to get the `releaseId` in your node backend.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. in my routes i had to do:

```
  console.log(req.query.releaseId)
```